# working with react components REACTjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a trouble in dealing with react components. My problem is already been answered over stackoverflow in several question but am unable to resolve my problem with them thats why I am posting question again.

my app-client.js file

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDom = require("react-dom");
var Router = require("react-router");
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = require("react-router").DefaultRoute;

var APP = require("./components/APP");
var Audience = require("./components/Audience")
var Speaker = require("./components/Speaker")
var Board = require("./components/Board")

var routes = (
    <Route handler={APP}>
        <Route path="/" handler={Audience}></Route>
        <Route name="speaker" path="speaker" handler={Speaker}></Route>
        <Route name="board" path="board" handler={Board}></Route>
    </Route>
);

ReactDom.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

And in my App component file I am trying to deal all those routes with 
this line `var RouteHandler = require("react-router").RouteHandler;`

And I am having 2 error in console as

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: Object
```

If anyone is concerned in look the whole code then its on github as well https://github.com/ijunaid8088/react-sockets
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are receiving stem from the use of this  that you have specified.  As far as I'm aware, there is no such feature within React-Router.

***Removing your use of it in your APP file will fix these 2 errors.***

What I'm guessing you want to achieve is for the your APP to be the container the component and for your components to appear as children when on each Route.

---

### Suggested solution:

### within app-client.js:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDom = require("react-dom");
var Router = require("react-router").Router;
var Route = require("react-router").Route;
var IndexRoute = require("react-router").IndexRoute;
var hashHistory = require("react-router").hashHistory;

var APP = require("./components/APP");
var Audience = require("./components/Audience")
var Speaker = require("./components/Speaker")
var Board = require("./components/Board")

ReactDom.render(
    <Router history={ hashHistory } >
        <Route path="/" component={ APP }>
            <IndexRoute component={ Audience}/>
            <Route name="speaker" path="speaker" component={Speaker}></Route>
            <Route name="board" path="board" component={Board}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

Notice a property history has been set to hashHistory (which has to be required from React-Router.

The above JSX will make the APP component appear on the root ("/")  path.  In order to make the Audience component appear on the root  path, I've set the component to  so that React-Router  knows to render it as a child of APP [see Index Routes/ Index Links  for more info](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md).

The other components (Speaker and Board) will  appear in place of Audience when their relevant paths are visited.  Also notice how I set a property of *component* for each route rather than *handler*.

With the Audience, Speaker and Board components now wired up to be child Routes of the APP component we can move onto the next file:

### within APP.js:

#### 3) Ensure child routes are rendered

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can reference which child routes to render using:

```
{this.props.children}
```

React-Router handles which ones are passed in depending on route path.

> **EDIT:**
>  You could set up your project to use ES6 imports and exports as well as destructuring so the require functions could be
>   written like:
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
> import {Router, IndexRoute, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
> ...
> etc.
> ```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and got error as 
bundle.js:1302 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).printWarning @ bundle.js:1302
bundle.js:866 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: I've noticed the way I worded it originally is incorrect.  Still surround step (2) with var routes

Comment: so now? what are you suggesting? can you clone the repo and make changes to make it work?

Comment: see my ammendment to step 2, you should still be setting routes to the new JSX and NOT emitting that step.  Otherwise you'd have invalid JSX

Comment: It's the require functions.  I generally use ES6 so attempted to re-write them in step 1, please take another look.  The new setup should work for sure.

Comment: I've re-written my answer again to avoid any confusion.  The changes that I made require an addition of property off react-router called {hashHistory}, although you can use the alternatives detailed [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md).

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked but its only giving me Audience route.. on / why other routes are not working? as board and speaker?

Comment: other also worked i replaced handler with component.. Thanks am accepting the answer can you refer me something to learn reactjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126885/discussion-between-pineda-and-ijunaidfarooq).